# Android GraphView Library in android

Tags: android, graph, alignment, android-graphview

I am new to android , I used GraphView library to draw a BarGraph it looks ok but the problem is that the horizontal labels does not matches with the bar and the width of bars is too small as compared to labels.
Yes i have used the setHorizontalLabels(10) methods as i need the horizontal vales as Integers 
But still problem is the same
Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my own 
Its now working according to my need.

the solution is to customize the library project

1)download zip GraphView-Master from the below 
[Link-]
[https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/archive/master.zip][1](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/archive/master.zip)

2)Just modify the things as said below
There are quick fixes:

```
 // In BarGraphView.java

    //float colwidth = (graphwidth - (2 * border)) / values.length;
    float colwidth = graphwidth / values.length;

    // In GraphView.java

    // horizontal labels + lines
    int hors = horlabels.length;
    for (int i = 0; i <= horlabels.length; i++) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
    canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    if (i < horlabels.length) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x + (graphwidth / hors) / 2, height - 4, paint);
    }
    }
```

3) Use the new generated lib in your project 
 Please do not forget to remove the previously used .jar else it will give you Dalvik error

4)The same issue is been discussed here on this [link](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/14)

Hope this would be helpful